# Ubuntu 18.04: how to change keyboard layout from a script?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

In Ubuntu 16.04, the following thing worked:

```
/usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0
```

But after upgrading to 18.04, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: It still works in 20.04 with `lightdm` while the accepted answer doesn't. OTOH, if you are using `gdm`, then only the accepted answer works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method of switching keyboard layouts has been deprecated. The new, just *slightly* more cryptic way is this:

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell \
    --object-path /org/gnome/Shell \
    --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval \
    "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[1].activate()"
```

(credits: https://www.mail-archive.com/gnome-shell-list@gnome.org/msg08988.html)

The number in `inputSources[1]` defines which layout you want. So, if you have two different layouts configured, it will be 0 or 1. You can get a list of the configured layouts by using this command:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
[('xkb', 'us+intl-unicode'), ('xkb', 'us')]
```

Answer (score 3):

The Sebastian's answer is great, I can confirm that it works much faster than the previous method that I used:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'us')]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'ru'), ('ibus', 'googlepinyin')]"
```

To clearify his answer, the number in square brackets (`inputSources[1]`) is starting from 0, in my case 0 will be us, 1 ru and 2 pinyin in the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell \
    --object-path /org/gnome/Shell \
    --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval \
    "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[1].activate()"
```

You can store shell scripts for each language switch in your home directory, for example /home/user_name/.keyboard/langXX.sh. Remember to allow executing them.

Then you need to add shortcuts in Settings/Devices/Keyboard/Custom Shortcuts:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULdrx.png)

Answer (score 0):

In 2024, the `gdbus call … org.gnome.Shell.Eval …"` is not working. It is deprecated. You could try to resurrect the `Eval` with [ramottamado/eval-gjs](https://github.com/ramottamado/eval-gjs), but you must understand how unsafe it is.

Most of the other methods you'll find on this site (`gsettings` / `setxkbmap`) are no good as well.

So, I've made my own GNOME Shell Extension and I'm sharing it with the world: [Shyriiwook](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6691/shyriiwook/) (also available @ GitHub: [madhead/shyriiwook](https://github.com/madhead/shyriiwook)).

This is a very simple, minimalist extension. It doesn't have any GUI. After installing it, a new D-Bus interface would be exposed in your GNOME Shell session. You could query it for the current configuration or call a method to activate the desired layout:

```shell
$ gdbus introspect \
    --session \
    --dest org.gnome.Shell \
    --object-path /me/madhead/Shyriiwook \
    --only-properties

node /me/madhead/Shyriiwook {
  interface me.madhead.Shyriiwook {
    properties:
      readonly as availableLayouts = ['us', 'de', 'jp'];
      readonly s currentLayout = 'us';
  };
};

$ gdbus call \
    --session \
    --dest org.gnome.Shell \
    --object-path /me/madhead/Shyriiwook \
    --method me.madhead.Shyriiwook.activate "de"
```

This is easily scriptable, and you can even put this command raw into a custom shortcut under the "Settings" → "Keyboard" → "Keyboard Shortcuts" → "View and Customise Shortcuts" → "Custom Shortcuts".